# mysqldump wampee fails

Tags: mysql, wampserver

I'm using the portable version of WAMP which is "Wampee" 2.1-beta-2 on Windows XP.

Im launching C:\Wampee-2.1-beta-2\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.8\bin\mysql.exe in order to try a mysqldump.

I do:

```
mysqldump -u root -p database_name > backup.sql
```

And it answsers "You have an error in your SQL syntax [..]"

Even this command give me the same result:

```
mysqldump --help;
```

How to know if mysqldump is installed and/or enabled? Or my syntax is really wrong?

Thx

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found! Mysqldump is another program so you can't access to it from mysql.exe

Open a terminal window such as cmd.exe. Change directory to mysqldump.exe:

```
cd /go/to/the/mysqldump/folder
```

Launch mysqldump

```
mysqldump.exe
```

Type your commands.

HTH! (: